# ASP.Net Core 3.1with AzureAd Authentication generating SameSite Error Chrome

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using Azure AD Authentication with ASP.Net Core 3.1 and when I Log In/Out I get a SameSite error in the console from chrome.

> cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://login.microsoftonline.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`

I can see in Application>Storage>Cookies i have a .AspNetCore.AzureADCookie with same site showing as SameSite None and a tick against secure.

Having looked through other questions and following code snippets I have seen multiple people report this is issue is fixed and others suggesting to add the following in the appropriate startup sections.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
})

app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
});
```

I have tried these options and combinations of these options but the error persists.

Additionally, I tried generating a new project with the built in template in VS2019 NetCore 3.1 with Azure Auth and it results in the same error.

Could someone help with what configuration needed to eliminate this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example site where this is happening? My initial thought here is that because the cookie is from `login.microsoftonline.com`, this is unlikely to be your code. However, I'm unsure if your configuration is affecting the remote service in some way.

Comment: Hi, I did wonder if that might be the case. I am going to create a developer account and see if I get the same result with another sample project. Thanks for the input

Comment: Note sure if you're still having the issue, but check out https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1037 - although that repo is for the JS library it looks like an MS/Azure problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I done further testing with ADAL MSAL on v1 and v2 Azure MS endpoint and got the same cookie warning. I used Azure code samples to ensure it was not my settings.

Comment: Hey @GreyMatter were you able to solve the issue? Can you post the solution for this one?